# Creating proxies for real objects

Tags: moq

I want to write an integration test using a real repository but also verify behavior of the repository

`SomeService(IRepository r)` calls `r.QuerySomething()`

And I've been trying to achieve this using Moq:

```
var mock = new Mock<IRepository >(() => new Repository());
mock.CallBase = true;
```

The trouble is that it never calls methods from Repository nor does it call it's constructor. The lambda over there is meant for getting ctor parameters (if type is a class) not for object initialization.

Q: How do I wrap `new Repository()` into a `Mock<IIRepository>` so I can verify calls?

NB: it works if the type give is a class but I cannot then use it for verifying since they implementatin is not virtual.

Alternatively is there some other nuget that can help me achieve this?

Comment: It's usually not good practice to mock the SUT. Usually how I verify this sort of behaviour is that the secondary member I want to verify invariably has a measurable impact on the overall result e.g., I can expect a certain result when the secondary member is invoked in a certain way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a technique that I use for testing brownfiled legacy code, it can probably help, in what you're trying to achieve. You can introduce a decorator into your tests project that wraps your original implementation, but also implements the `IRepository` interface.

```cs
class TestRepository : IRepostiory
{
   public TestRepository(Repository next)
   {
      this.next = next;
   }
}
```

Inside this class you can declare all the `interface` members as `virtual`.

```cs
class TestRepository : IRepostiory
{
   public virtual IReadOnlyList<Client> GetByName(string name) 
   { 
      return this.next.GetByName(name);
   }
}
```

Now you can use the `TestRepository` in place of your original implementation and also create a mock that verifies the calls to this class.

```cs
var repository = new Repository();
var sutMock = new Mock<TestRepository>(repository) { CallBase = true };
var sut = sutMock.Object;

sut.GetByName("John Doe");

sutMock.Verify(x => x.GetByName("John Doe"), Times.Once);
```

***NB**: The fact that you'd need a legacy code testing technique probably indicates to a code smell. I would recommend, as a first step, splitting the tests that assert the mock from those that assert the real implementation results (changes in the persistence layer).*